# How can I add a Pointer to array of pointers on parse.com?

Tags: php, pointers, yii, parse-platform

I am developing a backend for web app with Parse.com.
I have Sport and Stream classes. Sport contains many Streams. Sport table has column **streams**, which is an array of pointers:

```
[{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Stream","objectId":"VTq7sRxzzi"},
{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Stream","objectId":"8xJlFbq3YA"}]
```

I am creating a new Stream inside a sport. Then I want to update my parent Sport object, and try to add pointer  with php:

```
$parentSport->streams = array("__op"=>"AddRelation","objects"=>array(array("type" => "Pointer","className"=>"Stream","objectId"=>$newStream->getObjectId())));
```

New stream is created, and i get the id back and printed. But the parent Sport is not updated.
I get **Error 500
Must use setArray() or setAssociativeArray() for this value.**

I've tried AddUnique but still no luck. Please help!

**UPDATE:**

I've tried REST API, with this code:

```
        $className = "Sport";

        $objectIdToEdit = $id;

        $url = 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/' . $className . '/' . $objectIdToEdit;

        $appId = '';
        $restKey = '';

        //this is succeeded - the name got updated
        //$updatedData = '{"name":"someNewValue"}';

        //but this gives error "code":107,"error":"invalid json 
        $updatedData = '{"streams": { "__op" : "AddRelation",
             "objects" : [ { "__type" : "Pointer", "className" : "Stream", "objectId" : "".$newStreamId.""}] }'; 


        $rest = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_PORT,443);
        curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,"PUT");
        curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$updatedData);
        curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 
            array("X-Parse-Application-Id: " . $appId,
                "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: " . $restKey,
                "Content-Type: application/json"));

        $response = curl_exec($rest);
        echo $response;
```

Server returns invalid jason error, code 107. I can not get the quotes work.
**What is the proper syntax for the $updatedData?**

Response of the server: 
{"code":107,"error":"invalid json: {\"streams\": '{ \"__op\" : \"AddRelation\",\n \"objects\" : [ { \"__type\" : \"Pointer\", \"className\" : \"Stream\", \"objectId\" : \"CVymNF0HGh\"}] }'"}

Comment: You should be using `json_encode()` to make the JSON for you, do *not* manually create JSON.  Create an array, set it how you like, then call `json_encode()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end this code worked:

```
$updatedData = '{"streams": { "__op" : "AddUnique",
     "objects" : 
     [ 
         { "__type" : "Pointer", 
         "className" : "Stream",
         "objectId" : "'.$newStreamId.'"
         }
    ] 
    }}';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I added one "}" at the end):

```
'{"streams": { "__op" : "AddRelation",
         "objects" : [ 
             { "__type" : "Pointer", 
             "className" : "Stream",
             "objectId" : "".$newStreamId.""
             }
            ] 
        }}';
```

Comment: still get "code":107,"error":"invalid json: {\"streams\": { \"__op\" : \"AddRelation\",\n \"objects\" : [ \n { \"__type\" : \"Pointer\", \n \"className\" : \"Stream\",\n \"objectId\" : \"\".$newStreamId.\"\"\n }\n ] \n }}"}

Comment: thanks for the last curly braces, this code worked:

    '{"streams": { "__op" : "AddRelation",
         "objects" : [ 
             { "__type" : "Pointer", 
             "className" : "Stream",
             "objectId" : "'.$newStreamId.'"
             }
            ] 
        }}';